# How can I delete all of my gnome sources?

Tags: command-line, gnome

I was trying to install some source codes using wget and apparently I accidentally downloaded every source code in gnome. I really don't want all of them at this time.

I don't know if they already compiled. How can I purge or remove all of them completely?

Comment: From where you have downloaded the source codes ? the URL i mean..also source codes literally means source codes, no compilation in general..

Comment: http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/ apparently...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The directories [here](http://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/) contain source files of various packages. Source files are meant to be compiled by you, hence there is no question of these being installed automatically after downloading.

So you can remove the files easily by traditional way i.e. `rm`.

For example if you have downloaded the files in `~/foobar`, you can remove these by (assuming there are no files other than these, be sure of the contents first e.g. by `ls`) :

```
rm -r ~/foobar/*
```

Or

```
cd ~/foobar
rm -r *
```